# PDO, prepare statement but I don't bind the value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is the different if I dont bind the value but I prepare the statement. It works in both way, is it bind having better security?
Here is the code

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$server.";dbname=".$dbName.";charset=utf8", $user, $pwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->prepare(UPDATE table1 SET a = 1, name = ?, last_seen = NOW() WHERE b = ?);
$paramAry[0] = "abc";
$paramAry[1] = "def";
$stmt->execute($paramAry);
```

OR

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$server.";dbname=".$dbName.";charset=utf8", $user, $pwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->prepare(UPDATE table1 SET a = 1, name = ?, last_seen = NOW() WHERE b = ?);
$paramAry[0] = "abc";
$paramAry[1] = "def";

$stmt->bindValue(1, $paramAry[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $paramAry[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. You can either use `bindValue()` or `bindParam()` before calling `execute()`, or you can pass an array of parameters to `execute()`.

It's common to use the array argument to `execute()` if you already have your parameters in an array, and use `bindParam()` or `bindValue()` if they're in different variables. But it's entirely up to you and your preference.

Comment: Reason why I'm asking because I saw the this PDO::PARAM_STR, it seems like you are telling the database this is a string value. Meanwhile, for the first example, system will check first then only write, should be slower if i think in this manner.

Comment: In the case of MySQL, the `PDO::PARAM_XXX` options are usually unnecessary. It will automatically coerce strings to the correct type.

Comment: Thanks, I got what you mean.